# Executing T4 template: Host is null while hostspecific="True"

Tags: t4, nullreferenceexception, host

I am trying to write a console program that takes the file name of a T4 template as a parameter, and then processes the template. This because I want users to be able to update the template without having to recompile the program.

The simplest solution I found was to create a second template within Visual Studio that precompiles to a C# class, which in turn executes my external template "Template.tt":

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>
<#
    string template = File.ReadAllText(Host.ResolvePath("Template.tt"));
    Engine engine = new Engine();
    string output = engine.ProcessTemplate(template, Host);
    Write(output);
#>
```

Within the Program.cs of my console program, I then execute this "calling" template:

```
string templateText = new Caller().TransformText();
```

Problem is that when I run this (F5), it throws a NullReferenceException on the first line in my caller template, because Host is null.

However, I thought that setting hostspecific to True would give me a Host.

What do I need to do to get a Host? Don't really want to roll my own.
Alternatively, is there a better way to execute an external T4 template?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586945.aspx) the hostspecific attribute only provides access to the Host-Property inside the t4 template. It does not guarantee the presence of a host. For design-time templates (that are transformed in visual studio) Visual Studio and it's T4 engine provides this host. Unfortunately the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.dll is not a redistributable assembly. So you won't have that host in a run-time scenario.

As you stated, you would need to write a complete T4 engine and host yourself...

If your users need to write/alter the t4 templates, they have knowledge about programming and writing text templating. Could you think of a way to make them use visual studio in any way?

Alternatively (if the changes those user make are small) you could try to use a precompiled template that works on some other input (xml-file, ini-file, command-line-parameters, ...).

Sorry for not having better news...

Comment: This was helpful because I know that `Mono.TextTemplating` is the T4 engine you host yourself!

Answer (score 0):

The actual custom (command line app based) T4 host is not too difficult to implement, I don't recall off my head where I got the code but here are the links of our T4 modular console-app runner:
https://github.com/abstractiondev/absbuilder

The actual command line host is here:
https://github.com/abstractiondev/absbuilder/blob/master/AbstractionBuilder/CustomCmdLineHost.cs

For referencing the T4 parts, we've ran the tooling with Mono runtime / MonoDevelop environments in Linux, now based on the tests (thats 1-2 years ago), I recall that MonoDevelop's T4 was completely compatible and available as source code with some very sensible licensing (MIT or Apache 2.0 if I recall properly).